# Is it possible to generate a report from JIRA or Greenhopper on what code has changed?

Tags: svn, report, jira, confluence, greenhopper

We have the confluence suite.

Using this, is it possible to produce a report highlighting what classes have changed?

JIRA items linked to GreenHopper via SVN+JIRA references is exactly the type of information I need.

Does such a report template exist?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on what information you are looking for or provide a screenshot ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get this out of the box is to get [FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/), Atlassian's repository browser tool.  With the latest versions you can embed FishEye content in a JIRA dashboard and get the reports you need without having to switch to FishEye.

As Francis mentioned already, post back here if you have more detailed questions.